# Adding field to auth_user table that can have only selective values

Tags: python, mysql, web2py, data-access-layer

I am creating a Web2py application for a retail store. The requirement is that I use the auth_user table and there are two types of Users - 'Normal' and 'Admin'.

My question is how do I add a field to the auth_user table which has the constraint that it can contain only two values? What I would want ideally is that when the login page is rendered using SQLLFORM, the field for User_type should appear as a dropdown containing the two values (i.e, Normal and Admin).

I have googled it and could not find anything satisfactory. Any help would be awesome. :)

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387672/web2py-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

After defining the `auth` object but before calling `auth.define_tables`, do something like:

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = [
    Field('role', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Normal', 'Admin']))]
```

For more details, see the documentation on [customizing Auth](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Customizing-Auth) and the [`IS_IN_SET` validator](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Range--set-and-equality-validators).